# Is there a possibility to declare 4 options and Java has to pick 1 at random?

Tags: java

I'm making a tank game. I want my enemies to launch at random from one side of the panel like this:

`scherm` means **screen / panel**
`breedte` means **width**
`hoogte` means **height**

```
public void launch() 
{
    //from upside
    x_pos = rand.nextInt(Tanks.getSchermBreedte());
    y_pos =  0;

    //leftside
    x_pos = 0;
    y_pos = rand.nextInt(Tanks.getSchermHoogte());

    //lower side
    x_pos = rand.nextInt(Tanks.getSchermBreedte());
    y_pos = Tanks.getSchermHoogte();

    //right
    x_pos = Tanks.getSchermBreedte();
    y_pos = rand.nextInt(Tanks.getSchermHoogte());

}
```

I want Java to pick one of these options, but I don't really know how to do this.

Comment: yes, you can generate random number through the built in function and you can provide that generated number as case in switch case statement

Comment: Are you storing (x,y) coordinate in `Point`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `java.util.Random.nextInt(4)` which gives you random numbers from 0 till 3. Then use a switch statement to choose one of your options.

```
public void launch() {
      int random = java.util.Random.nextInt(3);

      switch (random) {
        case 0:
            //from upside
            x_pos = rand.nextInt(Tanks.getSchermBreedte());
            y_pos =  0;
        break;
        case 1: 
          //leftside
          x_pos = 0;
          y_pos = rand.nextInt(Tanks.getSchermHoogte());
        break;
        case 2:
            //lower side
            x_pos = rand.nextInt(Tanks.getSchermBreedte());
            y_pos = Tanks.getSchermHoogte();
        break;
        case 3:
            //right
            x_pos = Tanks.getSchermBreedte();
            y_pos = rand.nextInt(Tanks.getSchermHoogte());
        break;
      }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much but my enemy only launches in the left upper corner and i can't figure out why

Answer (score 0):

You can put all your points in an array and select a coordinate randomly using :

```
    public static int getRandom(int[] array) {
        int rnd = new Random().nextInt(array.length);
        return array[rnd];
    }
```

You can use it for x and y coordinate provided you maintain an array separately for them. Even if you maintain one the code can be modified slightly and still be useful